# JavaScript regex not returning match group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the content in between square brackets within a string but my Regex isn't working.

RegExp: `/\[([^\n\]]+)\]/g`

It returns the correct match groups on regex101 but when I try something like `'[a][b]'.match(/\[([^\n\]]+)\]/g)`, I get `['[a]', '[b]']` instead of `['a', 'b']`.

I can get the correct results if I iterate through and do RegExp.exec, but from looking at examples online it seems like I should be able to get the match groups using String.match

Comment: You will get the matched groups if you drop the `/g` modifier.

Comment: When you're researching JavaScript or browser APIs, always be sure to check the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN). In this case, their [documentation of the `.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) clearly spells out the behavior.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the String `.match()` method, which has different behavior from RegExp `.exec()` in the case of regular expressions with the "g" flag. The `.match()` method gives you all the complete matches across the entire searched string for "g" regular expressions.

If you change your code to

```
/\[([^\n\]]+)\]/g.exec('[a][b]')
```

you'll get the result you expect: an array in which the first entry (index `0`) is the entire match, and the second and subsequent entries are the groups from the regex.

You'll have to iterate to match all of them:

```
var re = /\[([^\n\]]+)\]/g, search = "[a][b]", bracketed = [];
for (var m = null; m = re.exec(search); bracketed.push(m[1]));
```

Comment: This is not correct; your example solution yields `["[a]", "a"]`

Comment: `match` is just to test a string *for match* - it uses the full pattern, not caring about any match groups. Thus the result will always be a "full-pattern-match".

Comment: @EdCottrell yes, and that is the correct answer. The first entry in the array is the complete match, and the second is the content of the parenthesized group.

Comment: I understand how `.exec` works, but your example doesn't tell OP how to find `a` and `b`, as requested.

Comment: @dognose that is not true for regular expressions without the "g" flag. In that case, the return value is the same as it would be from the RegExp `.exec()` call.

Comment: @EdCottrell oh well I assumed that the OP was expecting the return value to include the matched groups in the "normal" way they appear; maybe not I guess.

Comment: @Pointy true. keeping the answer to keep comment chain "logical" :)